# How to redirect to Ajax-call in JSF?

Tags: ajax, url, jsf, commandlink

I have an "ajax execute"-tag embedded in a commandLink-Tag in my JSF-File, which works pretty well.

My problem: 
I want to execute this ajax-call directly by using a Get-Request.So far, I'm using only one html-file(index.html) without any parameters.

Is there any way to call an AJAX-tag directly by using url/get-parameters but keeping the ajax-tag in jsf?

Thanks guys

Comment: can you provide some code please. Are you using JSF 2.0? What do you mean by calling an AJAX-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your question title, "How to redirect to Ajax-call in JSF?", just add `?faces-redirect=true` to the navigation case outcome.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

To answer the question in your question body, "I want to execute this ajax-call directly by using a Get-Request", replace the POST command link by a normal GET link `<h:link>` or `<h:outputLink>` wherein you pass the parameters as `<f:param>`.

```
<h:link value="link" outcome="index">
    <f:param name="foo" value="bar" />
</h:link>
```

They can be collected and processed in the target page by `<f:viewParam>` or `@ManagedProperty`.